# extract PSD layer content

Tags: photoshop, psd

Can anyone advise on how I might best solve my "little challenge"?

- assume someone created a (not overly complex) design in a layered PSD file.
- the PSD has various LAYERs with given LAYER NAMES containing various TEXTs using different FONTS and SIZES and the text located at different POSITIONS in the design (e.g x/y coordinate of the upper left corner of the text frame/box)
- same principle for DIFFERENT GRAPHICS in various NAMED LAYER, positioned in various different positions in the design (e.g x/y coordinate of the upper left corner of the images) inside the various layers

QUESTION:

I am thinking of having some software/script written which in essence does the following:

- saves the images of each layer in separate files (e.g. in png) using the name of the layer in which the images resides in the PSD as the images file name
- exports a text file out-putting the content of all text elements, e.g.
  --- the text content of each text box
  --- the the font used in the PSD layout for each text layer
  --- the the font size used in the PSD layout for each text layer
  --- the position (e.g. x/y coordinate of the upper left corner of the text frame/box) of each text in each text layer

Could you recommend anybody whom I might contact who could do that?

I WOULD BE EXTREMELY GRATEFUL FOR SOME SHORT ADVISE !!!

THANKS  TOM

Comment: "Could you recommend anybody whom I might contact who could do that?"> Any decent programmer could do that. How much money do you have? :)

Comment: you could try using http://photo.stackexchange.com/ - its stackexchange site about photos.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need this, but I was looking for something similar ad I found a JavaScript library, [Melitingice Github project psd.js](http://meltingice.github.io/psd.js/).

I already tried implementing it for [PSD fonts information extraction](http://giovannimuzzolini.com/get-psd-fonts/) and for [layer export to png](http://giovannimuzzolini.com/psd-tools/) if you need some reference...

Hope it helps!